# Перетаскивание формы за любое место (контролы в том числе) + закрытие по клику на любое место

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Имеется форма без рамок с одним элементом axWindowsMediaPlayer.
По сути, что то типа окна плеера.
Хотелось бы передвигать форму за любое место + закрывать форму по клику.
Использую следующий код, но не знаю, что добавить в него, чтобы закрывать форму по клику.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    private HashSet<Control> controlsToMove = new HashSet<Control>();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        controlsToMove.Add(this);
        controlsToMove.Add(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && controlsToMove.Contains(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd)))
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: если у вас форма из единственного контрола, можно просто привязаться к этому контролу. Перетаскивать и закрывать по событиям этого контрола. Заодно и функциональность самого контрола не потеряете, он же вроде как интерактивный был, play/pause и все такое.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо rdorn за предложение. Решил таким образом.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_MouseDownEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MouseDownEvent e)
    {
        if (e.nButton == 1)
        {
            MouseDownLocation.X = e.fX;
            MouseDownLocation.Y = e.fY;
            x = this.Left;
            y = this.Top;
        }
    }

    private void AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_MouseMoveEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MouseMoveEvent e)
    {
        if (e.nButton == 1)
        {
            this.Left = e.fX + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.fY + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }

    private void AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_MouseUpEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MouseUpEvent e)
    {
        if (x <= this.Left + 10 && x >= this.Left - 10 && y <= this.Top + 10 && y >= this.Top - 10)
            Close();
    }
}
```